# Are there any implications of having a parent POM version number less than a child POM version number?

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus, pom.xml

I am pushing maven artifacts to nexus, are there any implications around having parent POMs with version numbers less than childs POMs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge no. Versions of modules in a multi-module project may differ in any possible way. However, I would recommend to keep one version for the entire reactor (all modules in it).

Comment: Totally agree with you. This woul be even painful with maven-release-pluginI think.